# Dynamic Control generic react-hook-form. Getting error TS2322: Type 'Control<FormFields, any>' is not assignable to type 'Control<FieldValues, any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

In my app I use react-hook-form with last version of MUI 5.11.
I have made reusable Select component:

```
...someImports
import { Control, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

interface SelectProps {
  control: Control;
 ...someProps
}

export interface SelectOption {
  title: string;
  value: any;
}

const Select: FC<SelectProps> = ({

  ...props
}) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormControl {...props} fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id={label}>{label}</InputLabel>
          <MuiSelect
            ..someOptions
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem value={option.value}>{option.title}</MenuItem>
            ))}
          </MuiSelect>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  );
};

export default Select;
```

When I use it in component, I get an Typescript error:

> TS2322: Type 'Control<FormFields, any>' is not assignable to
> type 'Control<FieldValues, any>'.

```
interface FormFields {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const { control, handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm<FormFields>()

<Grid container columnGap={5} alignItems="stretch" sx={{ width: '500px' }}>
      <Grid xs={4}>
        <Select
          control={control} - here I pass control and this is where control is red-underlined
```

I have tried few playarounds - nothing helps :((

Answer (score 0):

It's because, `control` in `SelectProps` is typed as `Control` from `react-hook-form`. Inside your grid, you are passing destructured `control` from `useForm` hook and its type is inferred from `FormFields`.

As both these types are different, TS error is thrown.
Extend your `FormValues` with `FieldValues`

```
interface FormFields extends FieldValues {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Or update `SelectProps` as

```
interface SelectProps {
  control: Control<FormValues>;
 ...someProps
}
```

docs: https://react-hook-form.com/ts#Control

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution when custom with MUI,hope it helpful !

```
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material";
import { Controller, FieldValues, UseControllerProps } from "react-hook- 
form";
type ControlProps<T extends FieldValues> = Pick<UseControllerProps<T>, 
"control" | "name" | "rules" | "disabled">;
export type FormInputProps<T extends FieldValues> = ControlProps<T> & 
Omit<TextFieldProps, keyof ControlProps<T>>;

function FormInput<T extends FieldValues>({ name, control, rules, ...props 
}: 
FormInputProps<T>) {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      rules={rules}
      render={({ field }) => <TextField fullWidth {...props} {...field} />}
    />
  );
}
export default FormInput;
```